# sqlite Select specific day of specific month and none specific month

Tags: sql, sqlite, date, timestamp

What I am trying to do is to select a specific month and a specific day from a timestamp. What I have tried is this:

```
SELECT t FROM test WHERE t BETWEEN '2015-08-01 00:00:00' AND '2015-08-01 23:59:59';
```

with 8 being the specifc month and 1 being the specific day but this doesn't return anything.

Another thing I would like to do is to choose a specific day of every month of the year what I have tried that I know is wrong but I am not sure how else to do it is:

```
SELECT t FROM test WHERE t BETWEEN '2015-01-12 00:00:00' AND '2015-24-12 23:59:59';
```

I can see why this wouldn't work as I take every timestamp from the day in the first month to the same day in the last month, but how can I do it?

edit: I found why it wasn't working for the first example the variable i had for day contained a number so when it was lower than 10 it only said # and not 0#

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data.  A small SQL Fiddle might also help us understand what is going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use a `LIKE` clause for this.  Also your between won't work for edge cases if you have milliseconds after :59.

```
WHERE t LIKE '2015-08-01 %'
```

and:

```
WHERE t LIKE '2015-%-12 %'
```

Also, regarding optimization, `timestamp` or similar has text affinity (even though the docs seem to allude to it being numeric).  It should allow for `like optimization` if you have an index, but using ranges will likely be better if you can manage it.  I would check the query plans.

Comment: what do you mean by query plans? I am still new to sql and am doing a bit of trial and error and havn´t heard query plans before?

Comment: @Sumsar1812 When you execute a query, it "plans" for the most optimal way to execute it. Sometimes you'll create indexes to speed up access on certain field (like in the `where` clause).  If you are doing this on a small amount of data or as a test or one time thing, it may not matter. But if it is something that will grow to be large, or used a lot then you will want to make sure it performs well.  One way of doing that is to check the plan for the query.